# Python Interactive Loop-Break

Tags: python, loops

I'm currently trying to accomplish a loop which stops on user interaction.

My first idea was to use signals which brought me to this:

```
import signal

interruptLoop = False
def interrupt_handler(sig, frame):
        interruptLoop = True
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, interrupt_handler) # handle ctrl+c

count = 0
while not interruptLoop:
    print count; count += 1
```

this results in an infinite loop, because the rise of interruptLoop does not affect the variable out of the handler scope.

I'd appreciate any advice about why python/signal behaves like that and how to accomplish my task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only missing one line!

```
import signal

interruptLoop = False
def interrupt_handler(sig, frame):
        global  interruptLoop  # You're missing this
        interruptLoop = True
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, interrupt_handler) # handle ctrl+c

count = 0
while not interruptLoop:
    print(count); count += 1
print("I'm done!")
```

If you run this, you'll see the numbers printed until you hit `Ctrl+C`, at which point you'll see "I'm done!" and the script will exit.

**Why was the `global interruptLoop` needed?**

Python doesn't require you to declare variables in your function scope. The way it determines what variables are defined locally for a function is to see which variables are set. So when you set `interruptLoop = True` in `interrupt_handler`, python sees this as a cue that `interrupt_handler` has a *local* variable. This local variable shadows the outer-scope's `interruptLoop`, which python is treating as separate. So your handler essentially just creates a local variable, modifies it, and then exits. Of course this doesn't stop the loop (which depends on the outer scope's `interruptLoop`). The `global` keyword signals to python that the inner variable is actually supposed to reference the outer one rather than shadowing it. For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) for a short explanation and [here](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) for a full discussion of python's variable scoping.